# Convenient way of 'using namespace' in implementation details (header only library)?

Tags: c++, namespaces

So i work on this library (header only) that has several modules and uses an inline namespace for versioning. Thus the fully qualified names can get a bit longer at times. I would like to use 'using namespace x' as an implementation detail inside the (inline) detail namespaces, but that pollutes the outer namespace.

See the example code on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/pdSXrs

I found two workarounds (see godbolt link) that do what I want, but seem to be overly complicated. Is there an easier way to do this? Should I just type out all the fully qualified names (and keep the error messages cleaner)? I would love to know what are the best practices for 'more complicated' namespace constructs.

Edit: added code as suggested

```
// think of these as in header files

namespace mylib{
    namespace module0{
        inline namespace mystuff{
            // this constant conceptually belongs to module 0 but might be used as an
            // implementation detail in other modules
            int myconst = 42;
        }
    }
}

namespace mylib{
    namespace module1{
        // I would like to use this, but pollutes mylib::module1 namespace
        inline namespace detail1{
            using namespace mylib::module0::mystuff;
            struct foo1{
                int operator()(){
                    return myconst;
                }
            };          
        }
    }
}

namespace mylib{
    namespace module2{
        inline namespace detail1{
            // this works but seems overly complicated
            namespace more_detail{
                using namespace mylib::module0::mystuff;
                struct foo2{
                    int operator()(){return myconst;}
                };
            }
            // might be very cumbersome to use if lots of classes
            using more_detail::foo2;
        }
    }
}

namespace mylib{
    namespace module3{
        inline namespace detail1{
            // is this a good way to namespace a library...?
            namespace more_detail{
                using namespace mylib::module0::mystuff;
                // not enough namespaces yet?!
                namespace devil_of_details{
                    struct foo3{
                        int operator()(){return myconst;}
                    };
                }
            }
            // useable for lots of classes/types in that namespace... but really?!
            using namespace more_detail::devil_of_details;
        }
    }
}

// think of this as myprogram.cpp including the headers
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    // polluted namespace. I can probably live with it, but it's not ideal
    // constant should only be visible in module0
    int x1 = mylib::module1::myconst;
    std::cout << x1 << std::endl;
    // ok
    int x0 = mylib::module0::myconst;

    // this is what I ideally want, i.e. not polluting module2 namespace
    int x2_error = mylib::module2::myconst;

    // this is what I ideally want, i.e. not polluting module3 namespace
    int x3_error = mylib::module3::myconst;

    // normal usage in cpp file
    using namespace mylib::module2;
    int x2 = foo2{}();
    std::cout << x2 << std::endl;

    // ok
    using namespace mylib::module0;
    std::cout << myconst << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: questions should be self contained. Please include the code in the question

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest namespace aliases.

```
namespace mylib{
    namespace module1{
        namespace details0 = module0::mystuff;
    }
}
```

While this makes the other namespaces visible, it does not actually import the symbols the way a `using` does, that is `mylib::module1` does not have a `myconst` member.

Also, note that so long as the namespace you are currently defining is part of `mylib`, there is no need to have `mylib` as part of the name. Even if you close `mylib` then re-open it.

That is:

```
namespace mylib {
    namespace part1 { /* ... */ }
}
namespace mylib {
    namespace part2 { namespace p1 = part1; }
}
```

`p1` will refer to `mylib::part1` so long as you don't specify that it is a fully-qualified name (`::part1`).